# Multiple binary responses per participant in a 3 x 2 factorial ANOVA

Tags: anova, binary-data, proportion

As part of my thesis in linguistics, I'm currently analysing whether emotions influence the use of adjectives in speech. In my experiment, each participant (N = 90) produced multiple independent sentences, and the presence of adjectives was coded as either 0 (no adjective in sentence) or 1 (adjective in sentence). This leaves me with multiple binary responses per participant. In preparation of statistical analysis, I've tried summarising the binary responses by turning them into a proportion per participant (i.e., if adjectives were mentioned in 4/10 sentences, the proportion for that participant was 0.4).

As for the analysis, I decided to use these proportions as a dependent variable in a 3 x 2 factorial ANOVA (emotion [sad, happy, neutral] x order in which visual stimuli were presented [order 1, order 2]). Initially, I was comfortable with this approach because after an arcsine transformation, the proportion data were approximately normally distributed across conditions, and variances were approximately equal (Levene's test p = .542). However, I've read that ANOVA isn't the proper tool for analysing proportion and percentage data, and that the arcsine transformation is also inadequate. I'm wondering now how these data could be best analysed using a 3 x 2 factorial design? I've seen people mention logistic regression, but since I have **multiple** binary responses **per** participant, I don't understand how I could apply this analysis to my data. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the ANOVA, which are the levels of the two factors?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly, but can't you use the counts and model them through a binomial regression?

Comment: smndpln: I have edited my question to include the levels of the factors

Comment: Does each participant produce sentences under each of the six conditions?

Comment: Hi utobi: I'm not familiar with the term binomial regression, is it the same technique as binary logistic regression or are you referring to negative binomial regression? I'm very inexperienced in this branch of regression analysis, hence my questions.

Comment: Hi mdewey, no, every condition consists of different participants.